# How to unselect selected row in LongListSelector in WP8

Tags: c#, mvvm, windows-phone-8, mvvm-light, longlistselector

I must say that I really dislike the LongListSelector in WP8 and like the toolkit version so much better.

First it is not MVVM compatible so I found this code to make it so.

```
  public class LongListSelector : Microsoft.Phone.Controls.LongListSelector
    {
        public LongListSelector()
        {
            SelectionChanged += LongListSelector_SelectionChanged;
        }

        void LongListSelector_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            SelectedItem = base.SelectedItem;
        }

        public static readonly DependencyProperty SelectedItemProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register(
                "SelectedItem",
                typeof(object),
                typeof(LongListSelector),
                new PropertyMetadata(null, OnSelectedItemChanged)
            );

        private static void OnSelectedItemChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            var selector = (LongListSelector)d;
            selector.SelectedItem = e.NewValue;
        }

        public new object SelectedItem
        {
            get { return GetValue(SelectedItemProperty); }
            set { SetValue(SelectedItemProperty, value); }
        }
    }
```

then I made a view model using mvvm light

```
  public class MainViewModel : ViewModelBase
    {

        public MainViewModel()
        {
           MyList = new ObservableCollection<Test>
           {
               new Test
               {
                    Name = "test 1"
               },
               new Test
               {
                   Name = "test 2"
               }
           };

           ButtonCmd = new RelayCommand(() => Hit());
        }

        private void Hit()
        {
            SelectedItem = null;
        }

        public ObservableCollection<Test> MyList { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// The <see cref="SelectedItem" /> property's name.
        /// </summary>
        public const string SelectedItemPropertyName = "SelectedItem";

        private Test selectedItem = null;

        /// <summary>
        /// Sets and gets the SelectedItem property.
        /// Changes to that property's value raise the PropertyChanged event. 
        /// </summary>
        public Test SelectedItem
        {
            get
            {
                return selectedItem;
            }

            set
            {
                if (value != null)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(value.Name);
                }


                if (selectedItem == value)
                {
                    return;
                }

                RaisePropertyChanging(() => SelectedItem);
                selectedItem = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged(() => SelectedItem);
            }
        }


        public RelayCommand ButtonCmd
        {
            get;
            private set;
        }
```

then I made a model

```
public class Test : ObservableObject
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
```

then I made the xaml

```
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage
                            xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                            xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                            xmlns:phone="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Controls;assembly=Microsoft.Phone"
                            xmlns:shell="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Shell;assembly=Microsoft.Phone"
                            xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
                            xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
                            xmlns:ignore="http://www.ignore.com"
                            xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MvvmLight2" x:Class="MvvmLight2.MainPage"
                            mc:Ignorable="d ignore"
                            FontFamily="{StaticResource PhoneFontFamilyNormal}"
                            FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeNormal}"
                            Foreground="{StaticResource PhoneForegroundBrush}"
                            SupportedOrientations="Portrait"
                            Orientation="Portrait"
                            shell:SystemTray.IsVisible="True"
                            DataContext="{Binding Main, Source={StaticResource Locator}}">

    <!--LayoutRoot is the root grid where all page content is placed-->
    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot"
        Background="Transparent">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <local:LongListSelector ItemsSource="{Binding MyList}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem, Mode=TwoWay}">
            <local:LongListSelector.Resources>
                <DataTemplate x:Key="ItemTemplate">
                    <Grid>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" FontSize="48"/>
                    </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>
            </local:LongListSelector.Resources>
            <local:LongListSelector.ItemTemplate>
                <StaticResource ResourceKey="ItemTemplate"/>
            </local:LongListSelector.ItemTemplate>
        </local:LongListSelector>
        <Button Content="Unselect" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="142,81,0,0" Grid.Row="1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Command="{Binding ButtonCmd, Mode=OneWay}"/>
    </Grid>

</phone:PhoneApplicationPage>
```

when I click on the first item in the list, the message box shows up, if I hit it again nothing happens. I then hit my button which nulls out the selectedItem(which in the old toolkit version would be enough) and try again and nothing happens.

Only way I can every select the first row is by selecting the second row which is really bad if say the list only has 1 item at any given time.

Weird thing is that a simple collection of strings does not even require me to set the SelectItem to null as it always seems to deselect but when it comes to complex types it is a no go.

Comment: It would be useful to see the code for ButtonCmd. The only way the change event isn't firing is if there is no perceived change.

Comment: All the code is posted, ButotnCmd will trigger the Hit() method that just sets SelectedItem to null;

Answer (score 1):

I've used the same code and ran into the very same problem. Reason for it is that your SelectedItem property overshadows the base.SelectedItem property. When setting it to a new value, not only set your SelectedItem property but the base one as well:

```
    public new object SelectedItem
    {
        get { return GetValue(SelectedItemProperty); }
        set 
        { 
            SetValue(SelectedItemProperty, value);
            base.SelectedItem = value;
        }
    }
```

Then you have a MVVM capable code and can reset the SelectedItem in your ViewModel as well (by setting it to null).

Answer (score 0):

you can easily achieve via in selectionchanged event

```
void LongListSelector_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            if((sender as LongListSelector).SelectedItem == null){

             return;
            }

            SelectedItem = base.SelectedItem;
            (sender as LongListSelector).SelectedItem = null;   
        }
```

Comment: hmm, this code breaks the app. I think it is because when the list loads up nothing is selected, when I try to select something the null check will stop it from being set.

Comment: @chobo2 why you want to save that selected item you will get that when you needed

Comment: @Romasz that I have put before making it null as he suggested in question

Comment: @techloverr Never mind. I just wanted to inform you that I've deleted comments (I will do the same with those two) - not to make a chat from this. So you can delte yours also.

Comment: Yes I preform an action on selection(I go to another view), Also is that not the point of selector to grab the selected item and do stuff with it? With your code check there it basically in my eyes takes out the selection point of the longlistselector.